# Is it mandatory to use 1 letter arguments in optparse?

Tags: r, optparse

I am using `optparse` in to parse arguments in R. Then I call the R code from command line and pass arguments as follows `Rscript myscript.R -a xx -b yy`. It works well, but I am a bit confused with the usage of 1-letter arguments like `-a`, `-b`, etc.
In my case I have 20 arguments… It's very inconvenient to assign a letter to each argument.

```
make_option(c("-o", "--output_path"), type="character"),
make_option(c("-t", "--data_type"), type="character")
```

If I use complete names `--output_path` from command line, I get an error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the exact error? What did your call to `Rscript` look like?

Comment: @MrFlick: My call to R script looks as I showed: `Rscript myscript.R -a xx -b yy`. The error says that I should use 1 letter arguments.

Comment: @MrFlick: Can I simply do `make_option("--output_path", type="character")`? Why is it necessary to use `c("-o", "--output_path")`?

Comment: That's the same command you posted above that you said worked. so you do want to use one letter arguments or you do not what to use one letter arguments? What exactly throws the error?

Comment: @MrFlick: Yes, this command works, but it works only with 1 letter arguments. I cannot pass `--output_path` for example: `Rscript myscript.R --output_path xxx`. My question is how should I change the code in order to be able to run Rscript commands with whole names of attributes: `Rscript myscript.R --output_path xxx` instead of `Rscript myscript.R --o xxx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any problems using the short or long names. When I specify both versions I can call with either

```
toargs <- function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][-(1:2)]
option_list <- list(make_option(c("-o", "--output_path"), type="character"))
parser <- OptionParser("test", option_list)

parse_args(parser, toargs("Rscript myscript.R --output_path xxx"))
# $output_path
# [1] "xxx"
# $help
# [1] FALSE

parse_args(parser, toargs("Rscript myscript.R -o xxx"))
# $output_path
# [1] "xxx"
# $help
# [1] FALSE
```

and it works with just a long version

```
option_list <- list(make_option("--output_path", type="character"))
parser <- OptionParser("test", option_list)

parse_args(parser, toargs("Rscript myscript.R --output_path xxx"))
# $output_path
# [1] "xxx"
# $help
# [1] FALSE

parse_args(parser, toargs("Rscript myscript.R -o xxx"))
# Error : short flag "o" is invalid
```

One letter arguments are not mandatory; they are optional. But you must have a long name.

Tested with `optparse_1.6.4`